# Using std::move() when passing an argument to a base class

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, move-semantics

Ignoring the sanity of doing what I'm describing, does using the `std::move()` function improve construction time when used to pass an argument to a base constructor?

```
struct Bar {
    Bar(std::string);

    std::string _s;
}

struct Foo : public Bar {
    Foo(std::string);
}


struct Bar(std::string bs) : _s(std::move(bs)) {
    // 1
}

struct Foo(std::string fs) : Bar(std::move(fs)) {
    // 2
}
```

So in this example, does the `move()` used in `Foo`'s constructor prevent an additional copy of the string being made?

And for clarification, does this design mean no attempt should be made to use `bs` and `fs` at points `// 1` and `// 2`, but using `_s` would be safe in both places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out, I recoded your example with a fake `String` class like so:

```
#include <iostream>

struct String
{
    String() {}
    String(const String&) {std::cout << "String(const String&)\n";}
    String& operator=(const String&)
        {std::cout << "String& operator=(const String&)\n"; return *this;}
    String(String&&) {std::cout << "String(String&&)\n";}
    String& operator=(String&&)
        {std::cout << "String& operator=(String&&)\n"; return *this;}
};

struct Bar {
    Bar(String);

    String _s;
};

struct Foo : public Bar {
    Foo(String);
};


Bar::Bar(String bs) : _s(std::move(bs)) {
    // 1
}

Foo::Foo(String fs) : Bar(std::move(fs)) {
    // 2
}
int main()
{
    Foo f{String()};
}
```

For me this prints out:

```
String(String&&)
String(String&&)
```

But if I remove this `std::move` from the `Foo` constructor the printout changes to:

```
String(const String&)
String(String&&)
```

So assuming a `String(String&&)` is faster than a `String(const String&)`, the former is faster.  Otherwise, not.

> And for clarification, does this design mean no attempt should be made
>   to use bs and fs at points // 1 and // 2, but using _s would be safe
>   in both places?

Correct.